# Do I need to purchase an iTextSharp license for an intranet application?

Tags: licensing, itext

This question may have been answered already, but I haven't been able to find an answer matching my scenario. I'm trying to understand when it's required to purchase a license for iTextSharp.

I want to use iTextSharp in an intranet application within a for-profit company. Can I use the free version? Or am I required to purchase a license? I will not be selling the application or the source code. The application will be used **internally** by members of the organization.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not about the internal/external use. It's not even about selling the application or not. It's just a matter of license:

- If you release you application under a AGPL-compatible license, you don't need to purchase an iText commercial license.
- In not, you'll have to contact their sales department, and purchase one.

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious, but can you define "release"? If it's an intranet application, where am I releasing it?

Comment: By releasing, I mean make available for the (intranet) users.

Comment: Ok Got it. What about choosing to modify (or **not** modify) the iTextSharp code? Does that make any difference?

Comment: The third answer in this question points the section about "derived work" - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960802/can-i-use-libraries-licensed-under-agpl-for-commercial-purposes

Comment: Keep in mind that modifying AGPL code does not force you to make your modifications public. The obligation you have is to make available the modified source code to the **users** of your application, and only them.

Comment: Ohhh thank you for pointing that out. So if iTextSharp code is not modified, i.e., my application is referencing iTextSharp.dll, would you say that counts as a modification / derived work?

Comment: As per AGPL, I would say yes, even if you just link the dll, your work is considered a derived work. But I'm not a lawyer,

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34191/discussion-between-user1620141-and-alexis-pigeon)